# Выделение текста цветом на второй и последующей строке в QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Столкнулся с проблемой выделения цветом нужных букв в нужной строке, но они выделяются в первой строке а не в нужной мне.
Мой код:

```
int begin = 10;
int end = 20;
QTextCharFormat fmt;
fmt.setBackground(Qt::yellow);

QTextCursor cursor = QTextCursor(ui->textEditgggg->document());
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfBlock, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 3);
cursor.setPosition(begin, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor.setPosition(end, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
cursor.setCharFormat(fmt);
ui->textEditgggg->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Answer (score 0):

По вашему коду не понятно что вы там вообще пытаетесь сделать.
Вам надо: 1) Переместить кусор в начало документа; 2) Переместить кусор на одну строку вниз; 3) Выделить все с текущей позиции до конца документа; 4) Установить формат для выделения

```
QTextCharFormat fmt;
fmt.setBackground(Qt::green);
QTextCursor cursor(ui->textEditgggg->document());
cursor.setPosition(0, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor); // Для начала ставим курсор в начало документа
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Down,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor,1); // Сдвигаем курсор на 1 строку вниз
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor); // Выделяем все начиная с текущей позиции до конца документа
cursor.setCharFormat(fmt);
```

Comment: Дело в том что каждая строка находится в блоке, курсор постоянно стоит в 1 блоке и там же выделяет буквы, а нужно чтобы он выделял буквы в блоке который я укажу.

Comment: Я делаю функцию как при слиянии в git, где он выделяет строки и в сроке выделяет символы не схожие с предыдущим слиянием, в цикле при не совпадении букв вызывается функция которая должна закрасить эти буквы по их индексу в строке где они не совпадают, вот у меня он все выделяет только не в нужном блоке @SergeyTatarincev

Comment: тогда пожалуй вам надо переформулировать свой вопрос более точно

Comment: Суть вопроса не изменилась. Как обратиться к другому блоку в TextEdit для выделения цветом букв.